# Pandas: get column indices from a list of given names

Tags: python, pandas

Let say you have a pandas dataframe input and a list of column names. What is a good way to get a list of indices (column numbers) for the columns represented by those names?

I assume it'd be something along the lines of:

```py
def get_col_indices(df, names):
    return [df.columns.index(name) for name in names]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
def get_col_indices(df, names):
    return df.columns.get_indexer(names)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need them to be in the same order, you could use [`pd.Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)

```
import numpy as np
np.flatnonzero(df.columns.isin(names))
```

Comment: I always enjoy encountering yet another `np` function which I hadn't used before lol